# probably an easy fix but cant fix myself

Tags: javascript

anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this, id like to make a welcome message that displays on startup which asks you your name and then welcomes you with a greeting dependent on the current time.

The issue I'm having is that the prompt will work if everything else is comment blocked but also won't display on to the page in white text

```
    var name
    name = prompt("Please enter your name.");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (msg);
    msg.style.color = 'White';

    var now = Date();
    var hrs = now.getHours();
    var msg = "";

    if (hrs >  6) msg = "Good morning";   
    if (hrs > 12) msg = "Good afternoon";   
    if (hrs > 17) msg = "Good evening";
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you have?

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the prompt will work if everything else is comment blocked but also won't display on to the page in white text

Comment: `msg` is undefined. You have to style the `Element` that you get. First `msg` should be `name`, second should be `document.getElementById('demo')`... which should really be more like: `var demo = document.getElementById('demo'), demoStyle = demo.style; demoStyle.color = '#fff'; /* 'white' is ok too */ demo.innerHTML = name;`

Comment: isn't it defined as a variable/empty string

Comment: Check your browsers **developer** tools console for errors - it will show you exactly what is wrong in this case

Comment: if `msg` is defined as you say (not in the code you posted) - as a string ... why would it have `.style` property?

Comment: yeah debug is saying it doesn't like: msg.style.color = 'White';   ...so it could be that

Answer (score 1):

1. you used msg before its declared
2. msg don't have style property as it's not an element
3. you never used name
4. you used white color, which is same as default page background color
5. you assigned value to innerHTML before its assigned to msg variable
6. date object should be created with new keyword 
   `var now = new Date();`

```
var name = prompt("Please enter your name."); 
var msg = "";
console.log(name);
 document.getElementById("demo").style.color = 'red'; // use other color because white is default background color and your text will not be visible
var now =  new Date(); 
var hrs = now.getHours(); 
console.log(hrs);
if (hrs > 0) 
  msg = "Good early morning "+ name; 
else if (hrs > 6) 
  msg = "Good morning "+ name; 
else if (hrs > 12) 
  msg = "Good afternoon "+ name; 
else if (hrs > 17) 
  msg = "Good evening "+ name; 
console.log(msg);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;
```

Comment: "*you used msg before its declared*" correction - before it was *assigned*. The `var` declaration will be hoisted, assignment won't.

Comment: yes, there are some more problems, please se corrected code

Comment: using this refined code it's still not working as its not displaying on the page upon completion of the prompt (p.s my background color of the webpage is black), could it be in the HTML as to why that is?

Comment: most probably because white color, use other color like `document.getElementById("demo").style.color='red';`

Comment: also make sure you have an html element with id 'demo' <div id="demo"></div>

Comment: Perhaps `var now = new Date();` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmvbgpo/)

Comment: see working example here https://jsbin.com/cugomopaki/3/edit?js

Comment: ok so if it works there and doesn't work on my end what could it be?

Comment: its very simple html and javascript code, if you can't just use that, then i don't think anything can help.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong like I'm saying it's not displaying to the webpage I think it could be my html that is already on the page as when i comment all that it seems to work

Comment: id like to apologize for me being an idiot and putting the script tag outside the body tag, all is working now thank you all for helping